# jQuery if then and

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a sticky navigation that jquery adds a background colour to on a scroll top of 100px or more. This is the jquery for that.

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('header').addClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
    else {
      $('header').removeClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
  });
```

What I would like to do is simply just add an 'and' after the 'if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100)' to only run this if the window size is greater than 768px. This is what I tried but didn't work.

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) && ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $('header').addClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
    else {
      $('header').removeClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
  });
```

Comment: The only mistake you've made is doing this `if(a) && (b)` instead of `if(a && b)` This has nothing to do with jQuery, and is simply javascript syntax error

Comment: @Manjeet Thakur simply put the first jquery code i posted above I want that code to only run when the screen is greater than 768px

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes is right you miss closing parenthesis

Comment: @Jamiec Yes are right. 

` $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(document).scrollTop() > 100) && ($(window).width() > 768)) {
      $('header').addClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
    else {
      $('header').removeClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
  });`

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that with your (fixed) code it will constantly be trying to remove the class `sticky-nav-bg` as the else will run on <768px screens. This might have no effect, but its not particularly efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Jamiec for pointing that out for me, very helpful indeed. What's the best practice to stop the else from constantly trying to remove the sticky-nav-bg on <768px screens

Comment: @rufus I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the other answer, the main problem is your `if` syntax. To combine two (or more) conditions you do it *inside the parentheses* like this

```
if(a && b){ ... }
```

However, there is another problem with your code as you've intended it. Your logic currently would say (in pseudo code)

```
if scrolled beyound 100px and the screen is greater than 768px
  add a class
else
    remove a class
```

Logically, this means that on screens smaller than 768px it will constantly be trying to remove the class when the user scrolls.

To change this, first wrap everything in the if checking the screen size, and then the if to determine whether to add or remove the class.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if($(window).width() > 768){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('header').addClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
    else {
      $('header').removeClass('sticky-nav-bg');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much for the in depth breakdown of what i did wrong and how to rectify it. It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding extra **()** in your if condition so you need to just replace this

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) && ($(window).width() > 768)
```

with

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100 && $(window).width() > 768)
```

Then it will work for you perfectly.

Comment: This is correct... however, it's probably better to explain what the problem is rather than just saying "change this to this".

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks very much indeed @BibhudattaSahoo

Comment: Okay great then accept my answer and close your question.